# Straight line intersecting $n$ parallel straight lines?

Tags: geometry

> Q) Through a fixed point $O$ a variable straight line $L$ is drawn to
>   cut $n$ straight lines at points $P_{1},P_{2},P_{3}....P_{n}$  if
>   $P$ is a point on the line $L$ such that OP is the H.M. of
>   $OP_{1},OP_{2}.....OP_{n}$ . Find the locus of $P$ ?

I began by assigning parametric coordinates to find the length  $OP_{1},OP_{2}.....OP_{n}$ , but I'm getting equation in terms of $\frac{X}{Y}$ coordinates . How do I proceed ? Also shorter methods are always welcome .

Comment: I think the only way out is to make the calculus, with O the origin of xOy coordinates.

Comment: @EugenCovaci are you sure there is no other way out of this , btw this question was given under 'Parametric form of straight Lines' .

Comment: You can set origin every point you want. O seams to be the most natural choice. I'm not sure there is no other way, of course

Comment: In general the locus is a polygon with $2n$ sides. You should try to prove that point $P$ lies on a straight line as long as $L$ is not parallel to any of the lines $OP_1$, …, $OP_n$. And after a 180° turn $OP$ is just the same, so that $P$ lies now on a parallel line, symmetric with respect to $O$.

Comment: @Aretino could you please elaborate im not able to picture the polygon , all i can picture is a circle of radius $OP$.

Comment: See here: https://tube.geogebra.org/m/JQoYj8us You can rotate line $L$ (blue) by dragging point $B$. In this example there are three lines with equations $y=x-1$, $y=1-x$, $y=2+2x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=mx$ be the equation of line $L$ (varying with $m$), while the equations of the $n$ lines $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ it cuts can be conveniently written as: $a_1 x+b_1 y =1$, $a_2 x+b_2 y =1$, ..., $a_n x+b_n y =1$. Finding the coordinates of $P_1$, …, $P_n$ is then straightforward:
$$
P_1=\left({1\over a_1+mb_1},{m\over a_1+mb_1}\right),
\ \ldots,
P_n=\left({1\over a_n+mb_n},{m\over a_n+mb_n}\right),
$$
so that
$$
OP_k={\sqrt{1+m^2}\over |a_k+mb_k|}.
$$
We then have
$$
{1\over OP}={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over OP_k}=
{1\over n\sqrt{1+m^2}}\sum_{k=1}^n{|a_k+mb_k|}.
$$
Suppose now that $m$ varies in an interval where the signs of all $a_k+mb_k$ don't change. In that case we can write $|a_k+mb_k|=a'_k+mb'_k$, where $a'_k=\pm a_k$ and $b'_k=\pm b_k$, the sign being chosen so that $a'_k+mb'_k\ge 0$. We have then

$$
{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{|a_k+mb_k|}=
{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n(a'_k+mb'_k)=\bar a + m\bar b,
$$
where
$$
\bar a={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{a'},\quad \bar b={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{b'}.
$$
It follows that
$$
OP={\sqrt{1+m^2}\over \bar a + m\bar b}
$$
so that $P$ is the intersection between $L$ and the line of equation
$\bar a x+ \bar b y =1$.

As long as all the quantities $a_k+mb_k$ don't change their sign while $m$ varies, point $P$ describes then a segment belonging to the line 
$\bar a x+ \bar b y =1$. But when $m$ comes to a value for which $L$ is parallel to some $r_i$, then $a_i+mb_i$ changes its sign, the values of $\bar a$ and $\bar b$ change, and thus $P$ describes a segment of a different line.

The result is just a polygon with $2n$ sides: I leave to you understanding why this polygon has parallel opposite sides.

Comment: Yupe thats an almost perfect answer and i totally agree with you on the $2n$ sided polygon but then sides of unequal length , how do we generalise an equation for locus ?

Comment: Have you ever seen the equation of a polygon? You have of course $2n$ equations, one for each side, and I explained how to get them. Alternatively you could find the coordinates of the vertices: just set $L$ parallel to $r_1$ and find the harmonic mean point $Q_1$ and its symmetric $-Q_1$, then take $L$ parallel to $r_2$ to find $Q_2$ and $-Q_2$, and so on. Your polygon has $Q_1,\ldots Q_n, -Q_1,\ldots, -Q_n$ as vertices. Notice that if some of the $r_k$ are parallel, then the number of vertices and sides is reduced.

Comment: But the answer given is that locus of P is a straight line.

Comment: That answer is wrong, unless the quantities $OP_1$, $OP_2$ and so on are to be intended as directed lengths, in the sense that they can be positive or negative depending on their position with respect to $O$. If so (but that was not explained in the question and telepathy is not (yet) in my powers) the answer is much simpler, because one may drop the absolute value in the formula for $1/OP$ and the answer is then the line of equation $\bar ax+\bar by=1$, with $\bar a=\sum a_k$ and  $\bar b=\sum b_k$.

Comment: Im getting a line of equation **$\bar ax+\bar by=n$**, with $\bar a=\sum a_k$ and  $\bar b=\sum b_k$ and why cant we consider $OP_{1},OP_{2}..$ as lengths of line segment of line $L$ between $O$ and $P_{1},P_{2}...$ ?

Comment: To get that result you need to allow for $PO_k$ to be positive or negative, if not you get a polygon and not a line! Do the construction with GeoGebra, if you don't believe me. BTW: I forgot to divide by $n$ in my previous comment, it should be $\bar a=\sum a_k/n$ and  $\bar b=\sum b_k/n$, so that my formula is exactly the same as yours.